# Game Programming - Should enemy functions exist in the enemy class or an enemy manager/collection class?

Tags: function, memory, duplicates, pool

I have a question regarding essentially how functions operate under the hood, and thus what would be more efficient in terms of space usage.

The use case is game programming, particularly in the context of C#, and the question is as follows:

Is it more memory efficient to have enemy functions exist in a manager class or in the enemy class itself, meaning if there's an Attack() function, is there more space used by having the function in the Enemy class itself, and thus theoretically duplicating a record of the function with each Enemy class instance, vs. having it exist in an Enemy manager/object pool class, and thus just having 1 copy in memory that all Enemies in the pool can reference?

Thank you.

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure how to even test this, as it's essentially a fundamental programming/computer architecture question that I'm asking - do multiple class instances duplicate their functions in memory?

I tried searching for an answer, but no results were yielded.

Comment: `do multiple class instances duplicate their functions in memory?` No. That'd be quite the waste of memory.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? If it doesn't work the way I thought it did, then how does it work, and if there are no drawbacks to having functions in the instance classes vs. the manager classes in this regard, are there any other drawbacks or benefits to using one vs. the other, or vice-versa?